# Why will .get() not read my Entry strings

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner and have invested a month in trying to learn how to get a simple string entries to attach to my variables such that I can display it elsewhere on the screen and then save in a file. But I keep getting This Error Message:

```
line 31, in header
Label(master, text=researcher, font=("arial bold", 12)).place(x=125, y=4)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'researcher' is not defined"
```

I have trimmed the following code from more than 600 lines that do work and give me beautiful screens, file reads and writes and executes button selections, but I can't get my core input entries to display and be readable. Thank you for any help.

```
# Intro Entry Test
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

##### Master Window
master = tk.Tk()
master.configure(background='lightgreen')     ## Background color
master.geometry('1500x900')
master.title(' Kansas Species Key 31xz ')         ## Master Title
master.grid()

### Create the Master Canvas #####
w = Canvas(master, width=1500, height=900)
w.grid()

### Print Header to screen
def header():
         **#### ERROR Occurs Here ###### **
Label(master, text=researcher, font=("arial bold", 12)).place(x=125, y=4) 
         #### ERROR Occurs Here ######

### Introduction Screen         
def intro():
    # Frame for Box
    content = ttk.Frame(master, relief="raised", borderwidth=6, padding=(3,3,12,12))      
    content.grid(column=0, row=0)

    # Frame for Introduction Box Content
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=10, relief="raised", width=500, height=450)     
    frame1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    esearcherlbl = ttk.Label(frame1, text="Researcher", justify=RIGHT, relief="raised",
    font="Times 14 bold")  
    researcherlbl.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

    r_var = tk.StringVar()
    r_name = ttk.Entry(frame1, justify="left", textvariable=r_var)
    r_name.grid(column=1,row=10, sticky=W)
    researcher = r_var.get()

    # Submit Button
    submit = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Submit", command=header)
    submit.grid(column=1, row=16)

##### Introduction 
intro()                         

##### MAIN LOOP ###########
mainloop()
```

I have tried more than 20 different versions, most copied and adjusted from examples, many in StackOverflow and have run out of ideas.
Thank You

Comment: Your code is trying to use `researcher` before you've defined `researcher`.

Comment: `researcher` is a *local variable* inside `intro()`.  It cannot be accessed from `header()` where you're trying to use it; in fact, it no longer even exists at that point in time, since `intro()` has long since returned.  And even if you could access it, it's just an empty string, the result of calling `.get()` on a newly-created StringVar.  The user hasn't even seen the associated Entry at the time you assigned this variable, much less had a chance to type anything into it.  The thing you need to save in a variable is the StringVar itself, and call `.get()` on it only in `header()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why will .get() not read my Entry strings

There are some more typos errors to fix it.

- In line 21, The indentation isn't correct in `header()` function.
- Move `r_var = tk.StringVar()` and `researcher = r_var.get()` at the
  top of `header()` function.
- In line 22, change this `text=researcher` to `text=r_var.get()`.
- In line 37, typo error. Change this `researcherlbl.grid` to
  `eresearcherlbl.grid`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

##### Master Window
master = tk.Tk()
master.configure(background='lightgreen')     ## Background color
master.geometry('1500x900')
master.title(' Kansas Species Key 31xz ')         ## Master Title
master.grid()

### Create the Master Canvas #####
w = Canvas(master, width=1500, height=900)
w.grid()

r_var = tk.StringVar()
researcher = r_var.get()

### Print Header to screen
def header():
         #### ERROR Occurs Here ###### **
    Label(master, text=r_var.get(), bg='red',width=25,font=("arial bold", 12)).place(x=5, y=4) 
         #### ERROR Occurs Here ######

### Introduction Screen         
def intro():
    # Frame for Box
    content = ttk.Frame(master, relief="raised", borderwidth=6, padding=(3,3,12,12))      
    content.grid(column=0, row=0)

    # Frame for Introduction Box Content
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=10, relief="raised", width=500, height=450)     
    frame1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    esearcherlbl = ttk.Label(frame1, text="Researcher", justify=RIGHT, relief="raised",
    font="Times 14 bold")  
    esearcherlbl.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

     
    r_name = ttk.Entry(frame1, justify="left", textvariable=r_var)
    r_name.grid(column=1,row=10, sticky=W)
    researcher = r_var.get()

    # Submit Button
    submit = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Submit", command=header)
    submit.grid(column=1, row=16)

##### Introduction 
intro()                         

##### MAIN LOOP ###########
mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]